# Coolant boiling but no overheating

Tags: honda, coolant, radiator, crv

Car has been fine, I just drove 3 hrs and when I got to my destination my coolant was boiling. what do I do? No overheating ever just had ac fixed an coolant filled. I have to drive another 2hrs tomorrow, not sure if this is something serious or just the damn heat. I have a 2007 Honda CR-V

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You said it's boiling. How were you testing or seeing it was boiling? Was this through the radiator cap or what?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the coolant is boiling you ARE overheating.  What is the ACTUAL temperature during boiling.  Are you running water or do you have a proper 50/50 coolant mix in the cooling system?  Otherwise your question is very unclear.